# How do I obtain intersection points between a line and a boundary in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a binary image of a human. In MATLAB, boundary points and the center of the image are also defined, and they are two column matrices. Now I want to draw lines from the center to the boundary points so that I can obtain all points of intersection between these lines and the boundary of the image.  How can I do that?  Here is the code I have so far:
The code that is written just to get the  one intersection point if anyone can help please

```
clear all  
close all  
clc
BW = im2bw(imread('C:\fyc-90_1-100.png'));
BW = imfill(BW,'holes');  
[Bw m n]=preprocess(BW);  
[bord sk pr_sk]=border_skeleton(BW);  
boundry=bord;        
L = bwlabel(BW);  
s = regionprops(L, 'centroid');  
centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);
```

Comment: I ain't sure, what your problem is. Do I get your Situation right: You have an image with binary entries `(0,1)`. Where the `1`'s are building the outline of a body (in your case a human). Now you want to draw a line from the center of the image to each bin which contains a `1`. Is that right? And if so what is exactly your problem and how do you want those lines saved? DO you need kartesian coordinates?... PLS try to give further details and what you have tried so far. btw welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Moreover, can you post a link to an example image? maybe a sketch showing what you are trying to do? Asking good questions is the key for getting good answers.

Comment: Please post a picture.  It's quite difficult to visualize this without one.

Comment: I have boundary coordinates and the coordinates of the center of the image as a two-column matrix .  Yes,i need the coordinates of the intersection points of lines drawn from the center to the border

Comment: If you draw lines radiating from some centre point towards a boundary, don't they interact with the boundary points at the boundary points? That is, I don't understand how your output would be any different from the original outline. A sketch or simple example (coordinates of centre, coordinates of a few boundary points, expected output) would help a lot.

Comment: clear all
clc
close all
BW = im2bw(imread('C:\Users\hossein\Desktop\dataset\fyc-90_1-100.png'));
BW = imfill(BW,'holes');
[Bw m n]=preprocess(BW);
[bord sk pr_sk]=border_skeleton(BW);                                                      boundry=bord;      
      L = bwlabel(BW);
      s  = regionprops(L, 'centroid');
      centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);

Comment: if you have any suggestions, please help me

Comment: Don't put code in comments, it is hard to read. Press "edit" up above and put your code in your question, marking it as code with the {} button. It is still not clear to me exactly what you want to do or what output you expect.

Comment: I don't get this problem.  How are these lines defined?  I agree with @nkjt.  If you are extending lines from the centre of the human until they intersect with the boundary... wouldn't the intersection points be at the boundary themselves?

Comment: Ok, if we draw a line from the center of the image boundary Does cut. I need the code to obtain the coordinates of the intersection points.

Comment: How are these lines defined? Are they a series of points, or are they parametrically defined with a slope and intercept?  If you don't make what you want more clear, this question is going to close and it'll be harder for us to help you.

Comment: @user3883254 - Also, you have a lot of code where you are obviously using your own functions.  Please explain what those functions are doing, as well as what the output parameters / variables from each of those functions mean.

Comment: Lines are drawn as a series of points is empowerment. I just want the points of intersection with the boundary of the image. For example, centroids=[x1,y1], border=[x2,y2]

Comment: function border_skeleton obtains Coordinates of boundary points

Comment: @user3883254 - OK.  I'll write an answer for you.  BTW, Google Translate == FAIL.

Comment: Someone please close this question.  The OP has no idea what he/she is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

## Step #1 - Generating your line

The first thing you need to do is figure out how to draw your line.  To make this simple, let's assume that the centre of the human body is stored as an array of `cen = [x1 y1]` as you have said.  Now, supposing you click anywhere in your image, you get another point `linePt = [x2 y2]`.  Let's assume that both the `x` and `y` co-ordinates are the horizontal and vertical components respectively.  We can find the slope and intercept of this line, then create points between these two points parameterized by the slope and intercept to generate your line points.  One thing I will point out is that if we draw a slope with a vertical line, by definition the slope would be infinity.  As such, we need to place in a check to see if we have this situation.  If we do, we assume that all of the `x` points are the same, while `y` varies.  Once you have your slope and intercept, simply create points in between the line.  You'll have to choose how many points you want along this line yourself as I have no idea about the resolution of your image, nor how big you want the line to be.  We will then store this into a variable called `linePoints` where the first column consists of `x` values and the second column consists of `y` values.  In other words:

In other words, do this:

```
%// Define number of points
numPoints = 1000;
%// Recall the equation of the line: y = mx + b, m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) 
if abs(cen(1) - linePt(1)) < 0.00001 %// If x points are close
    yPts = linspace(cen(2), linePt(2), numPoints); %// y points are the ones that vary
    xPts = cen(1)*ones(numPoints, 1); %//Make x points the same to make vertical line
else %// Normal case
    slp = (cen(2) - linePt(2)) / cen(1) - linePt(1)); %// Solve for slope (m)
    icept = cen(2) - slp*cen(1); %// Solve for intercept (b)
    xPts = linspace(cen(1), linePt(1), numPoints); %// Vary the x points
    yPts = slp*xPts + icept; %// Solve for the y points
end
linePoints = [xPts(:) yPts(:)]; %// Create point matrix
```

## Step #2 - Finding points of intersection

Supposing you have a 2D array of points `[x y]` where `x` denotes the horizontal co-ordinates and `y` denotes the vertical co-ordinates of your line. We can simply find the distance between all of these points in your boundary with all of your points on the line.  Should any of the points be under a certain threshold (like `0.0001` for example), then this indicates an intersection.  Note that due to the crux of floating point data, we can't check to see if the distance is `0` due to the step size in between each discrete point in your data.

I'm also going to assume `border_skeleton` returns points of the same format.  This method works without specifying what the centroid is.  As such, I don't need to use the centroids in the method I'm proposing.  Also, I'm going to assume that your line points are stored in a matrix called `linePoints` that is of the same type that I just talked about.

In other words, do this:

```
numBoundaryPoints = size(boundry, 1); %// boundary is misspelled in your code BTW
ptsIntersect = []; %// Store points of intersection here
for idx = 1 : numBoundaryPoints %// For each boundary point...
    %//Obtain the i'th boundary point
    pt = boundry(:,idx);

    %//Get distances - This computes the Euclidean distance
    %//between the i'th boundary point and all points along your line
    dists = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, linePoints, pt).^2, 2));

    %//Figure out which points intersect and store
    ptsIntersect = [ptsIntersect; linePoints(dists < 0.0001, :)];
end
```

In the end, `ptsIntersect` will store all of the points along the boundary that intersect with this line.  Take note that I have made a lot of assumptions here because you haven't (or seem reluctant to) give any more details than what you've specified in your comments.

---

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. Please write way down the line. The line must be drawn from the center of the image.

Comment: @user3883254 - How about I say **no** and let you figure that out by yourself?  I assume that the line is already provided by you.  To be honest, I've given you way more than the people who have commented on your post have given you.  Why don't we chalk this up to a learning exercise and you do the rest by yourself?  Good luck!

Comment: How do you get the line? . Please help me. Line must be drawn from the center

Comment: @user3883254 - Edited.  I placed a method on how to draw a line from the centre, but **you must** choose where the end point of the line is.  This is as far as I go (and honestly more than you deserve).  Good luck.

Comment: @user3883254 - .... then what is the whole point of this exercise?  If the last point is on the boundary, **shouldn't the intersection point be the boundary**?  If you were to draw an infinite number of lines from the centre to the boundary, wouldn't the final result be the boundary itself?  This is like trying to take a picture of a picture when the first picture would suffice.  Now I **really** have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Suppose that the tip hand is placed on the side of the body , In this case, the line is drawn in the center of the human body in two-point boundary cuts

Comment: @user3883254 In that case, the code that I wrote will work.  You just have to specify `linePt` to be any point along the boundary.  I think I have solved your problem, so good luck.

Comment: Thank you. But did you give application error. Just draw a line and does not specify the location of the intersection points. please help

Comment: @user3883254 You have to use **BOTH** pieces of code.  Step #1 to get the line points, then use step #2 to get the line intersection points.  Mind you, this code is untested so if it doesn't work, I'm going to leave that to you to figure out.  Have fun!

Comment: have done your work.But it's not all the points of intersection Just a point of intersection of the boundary gain